# Amazon CloudSearch filter query on range of values

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to filter a CloudSearch using the filterQuery property. I would like to pass a non-successive range of values, but can't seem to understand the correct syntax. I can pass a single value:

`filterQuery = (and category_id:97)`

and a range:

`filterQuery = (or category_id:[97,98])`

but not this:

`filterQuery = (or category_id:[97,98,135,172])`

The API docs are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/search-api.html#structured-search-syntax

I think the long-hand way of using `(or category_id:97) (or category_id:97)` also works, but seems like I'm missing a trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really the correct "long-hand" syntax, but it *is* the only way to do it:

```
(or category_id:97 category_id 98 ...)
```

Comment: Sorry, I had just typed it from memory - more of an example - but thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a limit of 50 terms within the filter. How can you search a larger range of values? I have asked this separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208275/aws-cloudsearch-how-to-search-a-large-subset)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
(or field=category_id 97 98 135 172)
```

You could even include a range

```
(or field=category_id 97 98 category_id:[100,105] 135 172)
```